# Using RPC over email?

Tags: python, web-services, email, asynchronous

Can someone tell me how they have done this in some form, be it XML-RPC, SOAP, bespoke etc. Not too worried on the packet format.

I am interested in doing some sort of RPC over email, setting up a program to receive commands via email from another application(s) or even from users on a subscription list. Basically the idea is you give someone the email address and then send messages to active commands, and the response is back in email. A good example of where I would be taking this is maybe a chess program, where time is irrelevant but delivery is everything and sequential ordering of moves is a given.

I would be most interested in the experiences of others, especially with the nature of email and any idiosyncratic behaviour that I should be aware of.

I have quite a bit of experience of RPC over Message Queues and asynchronous delivery, but would like to come up with a solution where I shift the communications on to hotmail or gmail, freeing up my servers and the headache of the asynchronous intercoms.

Comment: +1 for considering an alternative to HTTP. I'd really be interested to see if it could be done over the Gopher protocol. :-)

Comment: @apheta crickey that's a blast from the past, plus 1 for even remembering gopher and bringing it up in a conversation :)

Comment: I would be using the email system strictly for message passing and it would be stateless in operation. I was thinking along the lines of SOAP over Email, would say an email protocol but I am thinking of googlemail or hotmail. I guess these operate over http. sorry about that @amphet.

Answer (score 2):

You could use **[fetchmail](http://fetchmail.berlios.de/fetchmail-man.html#9)** like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
while sleep 1
do
    fetchmail --idle --mda python program_that_accepts_email_with_headers_on_stdin.py
done
```

Then Your program can do various things from querying database, through using some http services, to sending an email to someone. The way it works is first it sleeps for a second, then it checks the email box according to settings You need to place in ~/.fetchmailrc (read `man fetchmail` for info on how to do that). If it finds any email, it invokes Your program, if not and the loop goes back to the start point. If it doesn't find any emails, it **waits** until an email will arrive (or the mail server will restart).

The bottom line is that if the said system is not heavily loaded, it will **almost instantly** react to emails (usually You send an email with command, wait 3 seconds and You have a reply in Your inbox).

NOTE: halting (`--idle`) only works with IMAP servers. With pop servers You could do the same but sleep 10 seconds instead of 1. Sleeping for 1 second is good because Your program may be ultra-fast and may create an infinite loop with other program (f.e. mailer daemon saying someone is on vacation) and usually it would be good to at least limit their looping frenzy to 1 email/second. I learned it the hard way :) Sleeping will be bad if You would like to process more than 1 email/second. If so, switch `sleep 1` to `true`.

Comment: You could say that in the question ;) I only use linux so it worked for me quite well

Comment: I like the fetchmail option, how does the loop work, can you give an example, would the loop be expensive, would like to know more, if using a bash script how would I sleep the task?

Answer (score 2):

I'm already doing this with Google AppEngine and Python. It's really simple.

In your `app.yaml` file you need to setup that you will using the email service and you file to manage them:

```
application: appname
version: 1
runtime: python
api_version: 1

handlers:
- url: /_ah/mail/.+
  script: mail.py
  login: admin

inbound_services:
- mail
```

Then create a `mail.py` file with something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import rfc822
import logging

from google.appengine.ext import db
from google.appengine.ext import webapp 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.mail_handlers import InboundMailHandler 
from google.appengine.ext.webapp.util import run_wsgi_app

class LogSenderHandler(InboundMailHandler):
    def receive(self, message):
        service_name, service_email = rfc822.parseaddr(message.to)
        service_request = service_email.split('@').pop(0)
        sender_name, sender_email = rfc822.parseaddr(message.sender)

        logging.info('Service `%s` activated by `%s`.' % (service_request, sender_email))

if __name__ == '__main__':
    application = webapp.WSGIApplication(
        [LogSenderHandler.mapping()])
    run_wsgi_app(application)
```

All you need to do is send an email to `servicename@appname.appspotmail.com`. Voila!

Comment: very cool. I like it. Needs to be served up by google though?, not looked at the appengine for ages, but I like this approach +1